# jQuery show hide div based on select value with loading-how to add loading element in this code

Tags: javascript, html

How to add loading function in this code? Anyone modify this please.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#colorselector').change(function() {
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<Select id="colorselector">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Select>
<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none">Ok janu i love you </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
            $('#colorselector').change(function(){
                $('#loading').show();
                $('.colors').hide();
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select id="colorselector">
       <option value="red">Red</option>
       <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
       <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </Select>
    //OUTPUT 
    <div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none">Ok janu i love you </div>
    <div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
    <div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
    <div id="loading" style="display:none">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: But how to add loading function , i mean when i select one option ,i want to show loading before output result.

Comment: @user3286559 you can add loading block and show/hide it when select option. look at my update